# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS can't find essential packages

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates

Two days ago I asked about having trouble finding the openjdk-8 repos from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It gets better -- it seems to be a general 16.04 LTS repo problem.

Context:  Installing from a Docker container (which means that it's running as root), `apt-get update` has just run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y --fix-missing [...long list of packages...]
```

```
Get:129 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu10 [68.7 kB]
Err:130 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-116.140
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Get:131 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.23-0ubuntu10 [2079 kB]
Err:130 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-116.140
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

The failure also occurs without the `--fix-missing` option. That was an attempt to fix it.

Has the 16.04 repo collection broken due to neglect?

Comment: Also running into the exact same problem. Also in Docker. It's not just you.

Comment: Rerunning `apt-get update` (around the time I'm writing this) seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thomas, it looks like you are quite correct, they fixed the repo.

For Docker users, creating your container -- you may have to use the `--no-cache` option to avoid building your system from a bad intermediate container -- will do the job.

For normal users, just rerunning `sudo apt-get update` will resolve the broken packages, both with the Java packages I spoke about earlier, and the libc packages described in this question.

Thanks to whoever went and fixed the repos!